# Windows 7 stops responding to my SYN requests unless I continue to ping the client

Tags: windows, tcp

Basic synopsis, my Windows 7 box stops sending RST, ACK packets to a client which is sending SYN packets after time.

What I know:

I have a client who sends a SYN packet, followed by a retransmit 3 seconds later, followed by a second retransmit 6 seconds after. After that last retransmit it tries again 20 seconds later with an original SYN and then more retransmits. That sequence happens forever.

Originally I would have a custom piece of server software answering and communicating with the client periodically for testing purposes but after leaving the software inactive for the weekend things went sideways on me. The server now no longer gets any traffic and the client seems invisible to my box.

However, if I send a single PING to the client, it's next SYN packet is met with a RST, ACK from Windows. When the client tries again 30 seconds later no more RST, ACK packets are sent unless I PING again. For my testing, I can issue a PING -t and it keeps things going but that is obviously not a solution.

Based on other posts I have tried disabling receive window auto tuning as well as a reboot (obviously). I am leaning towards some kind of fail-safe in Windows right now due to my constant client connect attempts but no server to responds to it? Could this be some kind of SYN flood protection? Windows firewall is disabled as well as my corporate Kaspersky protection.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: What hardware is between these two machines, are they on the same LAN segment separated by a switch? Are you passing through any consumer/commercial grade routers? Are there any Hardware Firewalls or NAT devices between the two machines?

Comment: It sounds like an ARP problem. How is the machine supposed to know what Ethernet hardware address to send the reply to?

Comment: Ah right, same LAN, and the ARP tables seem to be correct on the PC. I am seeing the correct MAC addresses as well. There are no hardware firewalls in the way at all and all known soft firewalls are completely disabled. That is my biggest suspicion that some kind of firewall or something is in the way but I can't see anything at all.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I seem to be having a very similar problem where I'm trying to establish a TCP connection to a server, but the server is not responding until I send a ping to the server.